# How to understand strings with pointers

Tags: c, loops, pointers, while-loop, c-strings

I have been studying the C language for the last few months. I'm using a book and I have this exercise:

```c
char vector[N_STRINGS][20] = {"ola", "antonio", "susana"};
char (*ptr)[20] = vector;
char *p;

while(ptr-vector<N_STRINGS)
{
    p = *ptr;
    while(*p)
        putchar(*p++);
    putchar('\n');
    ptr++;
}
```

I understand everything expect the `while(*p)`! I can't figure out what the `while(*p)` is doing.

Comment: It is called pointer dereference. It "returns" a value at memory address pointed to by `p`. Later in while block you also increase `p` with `p++` statement. Essentially your code goes through the string and waits for `NULL` termination. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: while(*p) doing loop body until meet '\0' - end of a string

Comment: as @tilz0R mentioned, you are simply dereferencing the pointer *p that you assigned to a char earlier, and using it inside a while loop parentheses as a check.

Comment: `while(*p)` is the same as `while (*p != 0)`. When does `*p` equal zero? Or, in the context of strings and characters, `'\0'`?

Comment: @machine_1 Dereferencing "pointer to X" yields "X"  , in this case X is an array of 20 char. So `p = *ptr;` is correct. `*ptr` is an array of 20 char, so the array-pointer decay conversion applies and `p` points to the first element of that array.

Comment: @M.M oops, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `p` in your code is defined as a *pointer* to a `char`. The get the *actual* `char` value that `p` points to, you need to *dereference* the pointer, using the `*` operator.

So, the expression in your `while` loop, `*p` evaluates - at the beginning of each loop - to the `char` variable that `p` is ***currently*** pointing to. Inside the loop, the `putchar` call also uses this *dereference* operator **but then increments the pointer's value** so, after sending that character to the output, the *pointer* is incremented (the `++` operator) and it then points to the *next* character in the string.

Conventionally (in fact, virtually always), character strings in `C` are `NUL`-terminated, meaning that the end of the string is signalled by having a character with the value of zero at the end of the string.

When the `while` loop in your code reaches this `NUL` terminator, the value of the expression `*p` will thus be ZERO. And, as ZERO is equivalent to a logical "false" in `C` (any non-zero value is considered "true"), the `while` loop will end.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.8.5 Iteration statements)

> 4 An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be
>   executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to
>   0.

In this part of the program

```
p = *ptr;
while(*p)
//…
```

the pointer `p` points to the first character of a current string. String in C is a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

So let's for example the pointer initially points to the first character of the string `"ola"`. The string is represented in the corresponding character array like

```
{ 'o', 'l', 'a', '\0' }
```

The condition in the loop

```
while(*p)
```

may be rewritten like

```
while(*p != 0 )
```

So the loop will be executed for all characters of the string except the last zero-terminated character and there will be outputted the first three characters of the string.

Pay attention to that (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 3 The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to
>   the relational operators except for their lower precedence.108) **Each
>   of the operators yields 1 if the speciﬁed relation is true and 0 if it
>   is false.** The result has type int. For any pair of operands, exactly
>   one of the relations is true.